# undefined columns selected - in R while trying to multiply two dataframes

Tags: python, r, pandas

I am trying to multiply two dataframes but it's not working as I'm getting this error :

```
Error in `[.data.frame`(., select(sewer_and_water, power, roads_and_bridges,  : 
  undefined columns selected
```

I have created this dataframe:

```
aggregated_data_mc1_imp <- Estimated_Damage_mc1_reports_data_Imputed_Values %>%
  mutate(interval = lubridate::minute(Estimated_Damage_mc1_reports_data_Imputed_Values$time) %/% 5) %>%
  group_by(time, interval, sewer_and_water, power, roads_and_bridges, medical, buildings, shake_intensity) %>%
  summarise(count = n())
```

[image]

and I have created this other dataframe:

```
agg_var_data_mc1_imp <- aggregate(Estimated_Damage_mc1_reports_data_Imputed_Values[, 1:8], list(Estimated_Damage_mc1_reports_data_Imputed_Values$time), var)
```

[image]

Now I am trying to multiply them and create a new dataframe out of these two where I multiply based on time.

So that I have a new dataframe like this:

[image]

So that each row is multiplied based on time. I have added some calculations in the picture but not for all of the datapoints. But I hope you get the idea.

what I have tried is this:

```
df3 <- agg_var_data_mc1_imp %>% select(sewer_and_water, power, roads_and_bridges, medical, buildings, shake_intensity)[match(aggregated_data_mc1_imp$time, agg_var_data_mc1_imp$Group.1,)] * aggregated_data_mc1_imp[-1]
```

but it's not working as I'm getting this error:

```
Error in `[.data.frame`(., select(sewer_and_water, power, roads_and_bridges,  : 
  undefined columns selected
```

if you can suggest a way to to do this in R or if not, then if you could suggest for a way in python would be appreciated too.

EDIT:

```
structure(list(Group.1 = structure(c(1586131200, 1586131500, 
1586131800, 1586132100, 1586132400, 1586132700, 1586133000, 1586133300, 
1586133600), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), 
    sewer_and_water = c(9.71428571428571, 9.84090909090909, 11, 
    7.14285714285714, 25.5833333333333, 8.55357142857143, 19, 
    12.8095238095238, 12.6944444444444), power = c(7.35714285714286, 
    11.8181818181818, 7.61818181818182, 18.1428571428571, 2.66666666666667, 
    9.98214285714286, 14.3333333333333, 18.4761904761905, 7.27777777777778
    ), roads_and_bridges = c(11.125, 13.7272727272727, 18.2545454545455, 
    11.5714285714286, 12, 10.125, 1.33333333333333, 10.9047619047619, 
    12.5), medical = c(5.64285714285714, 12.5151515151515, 13.7636363636364, 
    14.8095238095238, 10, 10.8392857142857, 24.3333333333333, 
    10.9047619047619, 8.36111111111111), buildings = c(8.26785714285714, 
    14.969696969697, 11.6545454545455, 10.6190476190476, 21.6666666666667, 
    6.83928571428571, 3, 8.57142857142857, 7.25), shake_intensity = c(0.267857142857143, 
    0.204545454545455, 0.254545454545455, 2.57142857142857, 0.25, 
    0.285714285714286, 0.333333333333333, 5.14285714285714, 0.277777777777778
    ), location = c(45.2678571428571, 23, 35.0181818181818, 7.28571428571429, 
    42, 31.125, 70.3333333333333, 33.5714285714286, 27.5), estimated_damage = c(0.6529805, 
    0.66033475, 0.249612054545455, 1.3670839047619, 0.214479583333334, 
    0.290629267857143, 1.86052233333333, 0.777290333333334, 0.616270277777778
    )), .Names = c("Group.1", "sewer_and_water", "power", "roads_and_bridges", 
"medical", "buildings", "shake_intensity", "location", "estimated_damage"
), row.names = c(NA, 9L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: ok... can you use the `dput` function to provide us the `agg_var_data_mc1_imp` data.frame?

Comment: `..... 1.23037366666667, 0.387822966666667, 0.86236705, 0.585598857142858, 
    0.89642321111111, 0.76630625, 1.9917523, 1.17004580952381, 
    0.376563066666667, 0.577926166666667)), .Names = c("Group.1", 
"sewer_and_water", "power", "roads_and_bridges", "medical", "buildings", 
"shake_intensity", "location", "estimated_damage"), row.names = c(NA, 
-1441L), class = "data.frame")` . I guess you want to see this.

Comment: yes, but please edit this in your question. The comment is not long enough to show everything correctly

Comment: okay I did, but do you need all the calculations? Bcz I put a ... to fit it in the comment.

Comment: sorry, but this is not the whole output. Your output should start with the keyword `structure`.

Comment: @DSGym alright, I get it. I'm sorry, I've put it now. You can see the first 9 rows there.

Comment: @DSGym was it okay this time? the output from `dput`? I edited it in my first question